# Obtaining coordinates when computing distance of a polygon to a line

Tags: arcmap, distance, coordinates, arcgis-10.1

I have a shapefile of a county.  I am interested in computing its distance to a line, which I've been doing using Near.  I want to know the coordinates on the line that produces the minimum distance.  How do I obtain the coordinates?

I use ArcMap in ArcGIS 10.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using the optional LOCATION argument to create and populate NEAR_X and NEAR_Y fields as described in the **[help for Near](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000001q000000)**:

"Specifies whether x- and y-coordinates of the nearest location of the near feature will be written to new fields NEAR_X and NEAR_Y, respectively.

- NO_LOCATION —Specifies that the x- and y-coordinates of the nearest location will not be written. This is the default.
- LOCATION —Specifies that the x- and y-coordinates of the nearest location will be written to NEAR_X and NEAR_Y fields."